# Can two Magento developer work simultaneously on same magento 2 website?

Tags: magento2

this is different topic but it's related to Magento 2
Is it possible to work two developers on same magento 2 website at same time without any confliction ?

If yes, can anyone guide me ?

Because there may be changes code override even it push on GitHub

Comment: Yes, two Magento developers can work simultaneously on the same Magento 2 website using version control tools such as Git. This allows developers to work on separate branches and merge their changes into the main branch once they are ready to be deployed. However, it is important to have clear communication and coordination between the developers to avoid conflicts and ensure a smooth workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for multiple developers to work on the same Magento 2 website at the same time without conflicts, but it requires proper coordination and use of version control tools. Here are a few ways to achieve this:

1. Use a version control system such as Git to manage the source code. Each developer can clone the repository, make changes on their own branch, and then submit a pull request for review and merge to the main branch. This way, any conflicts can be identified and resolved before they are merged into the main branch.
2. Use Magento's built-in integration with Git by installing the GitLab extension. This extension integrates GitLab with your Magento instance and allows you to use GitLab's features such as merge requests, code reviews, and access controls.
3. Use a development process that separates the different areas of the website, such as the frontend, backend, and database. This way, each developer can work on their own area without interfering with other developers' work.
4. Use a development environment such as Docker or Vagrant to isolate the development environment from the production environment. This way, developers can work on their own copies of the website without interfering with the production environment.
5. Use of feature toggle to add new features without breaking the existing ones.

It's important to keep in mind that different teams may have different workflows, so it's best to discuss and agree on a workflow that best suits your team. Additionally, it's also important to have regular code reviews, testing and deployment process.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's possible to do it. using Git in local and Github or Gitlab

1. Create a repo in Github
2. Clone that repo in your local repository
3. Create the tasks you need to do in the project and name them Ex: Task-#1 - . Assign the tasks to each developer.
4. Create branch in your local repo with the name according with the Task name Ex: branch-task-#1
5. Create a branch to merge all branchs with the name for Ex:Integration (branch name)  in Github and of course you need to have a copy of this branch in your local repo.
6. Everytime developers finish a task they need to merge in that branch (integration) in their local repo and push it to the repo in github in order to integrate both developers tasks, so the main project task should be "integration".

Remember you need to configure .gitignore file and include everything you don't need to update for Example vendor folder, etc